# std::string::find() not working with std::string as argument

Tags: c++, stdstring

I've run across something that does not make much sense to me when using `std::string::find()` I'm hoping that someone here is able to spot my error:

```
std::string testString = "PFAIL";
std::string response = "PFAIL\n";

if( response.find(testString) != std::string::npos )
{
    //do something
}
```

This code NEVER hits the `//do something` comment for some reason. Any ideas?

Edited: I meant that it never hits the `//do something` code block, which it should and it does if I express it the following way:

```
if( response.find( testString.c_str() ) != std::string::npos )
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: that's good? it means it always finds it

Comment: ..? For some reason? `PFAIL\n` contains `PFAIL`. What other reason do you want?

Comment: If no matches were found, `std::string::find` **returns** `string::npos`

Comment: Ok... I made a slight error... I meant to say that it never hits the //do something block

Comment: Your code works for me

Comment: Are you sure you are not reaching the `//do something` block ? Is this exact little piece of code not working ??

Comment: [As you can see](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=08e044b1b076ff879214eb521eb2bc02-bb452bed83d06e87c370fcabced7e96d), the code is working for some clang++ version (and correct). Therefore, please show us a [minimal **complete** example that **reproduces** your problem](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: That's pretty much the complete minimal example.... however I will respond below with a little more detail

Comment: Actually after giving it more thought... the example I've given above is a complete minimal example. The only difference with the code I'm running is that "response" has the output of a function call assigned to it. I've already confirmed that after the assignment `response` is equal to the string "PFAIL\n". And in my production code `testString` is a global variable set to "PFAIL". Then the if statement does the exact test I have indicated above. The problem is that when compiling and running this on Debian "lenny" if I pass in `testString` as a `std::string` the test fails

Comment: But if I pass in `testString.c_str()` to the find function the test succeeds. So after reading the comments above I'm starting to think there is a bug in the implementation of STL that is being used in Debian "lenny"

Comment: A complete example would be something that I put in a file and run a compiler on it, without having to add things like a `main` or code for tracing. Other than that, the compiler version could be interesting (not the version of the OS). If you're using `gcc`/`g++`, run `g++ --version`.

Comment: Ah... I see what you mean about a complete example. Really I was just wondering if anyone has run into this same issue. So if I need to provide a complete example then I guess this isn't a common issue. The gcc version we are using in "lenny" is 4.3.2. I will try to find the time to create a complete example but as I have a workaround (getting the c-string from the std::string) that isn't as important.

Comment: I'm sure this has to be an issue with either the version of the stl library for "lenny" or the version of gcc being used to compile. Since there is no possibility of changing either for the project in question then the workaround will have to suffice.

Comment: Ok no excuses any more :P I installed Lenny in my VM, added the buildessential and got "g++ (Debian 4.3.2-1.1) 4.3.2". Compiled and run the complete example I linked above, and got the expected output. Please try my example on your system. I bet the error is not in the code you shown here.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you should consider using straight logic in your if statements:

```
if( response.find(testString) == std::string::npos )
```

This logical expression could potentialy confuse you less. If the return value of find equals to `std::string::npos` then the string in `testString` variable has not been found in your `response` string.

Edited: i had the logic in answer the wrong way.

Comment: Well the logic isn't confusing me... it's the fact that even though response contains "PFAIL" it never finds it when passing in "PFAIL" as a std::string.... if I pass "PFAIL" in as a c_str() it finds it every time

Answer (score 3):

Your condition is the wrong way around from what you appear to be expecting. `npos` is returned if nothing is found. Since the response clearly contains the test, `npos` won't be returned and the body of the `if` will be entered.

Comment: Yes that was an error I made when typing in the question.... I had someone in my cube at the time... I was a little distracted,.... sorry